# How to post data from php to aspx page?

Tags: post, asp.net

i have a php page.Now i need to post data from this php page to my another aspx page?
can i post data from a php page to aspx page?

```
   <form method="post" action="http://localhost/.../friend.aspx?title=abc" enctype="multipart/form-data">                       
    <td ><input type="submit"  name="search"  value="SEND"/></td>
   </form>
```

is it possible?

thx

Comment: As far as I know this should work fine. But clean your HTML :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, without a doubt.

Questions like this come along all day long, an aspx server handles data exactly the same as every other server. the way the data is used on the server side is the only difference.

You can post forms to **any** where on the internet, and also to any type of web server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the example you wrote should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible. You only need to be careful what you're posting and what aspx page expects. Try not to mess with all those view state clutter.